# Xero and Filemaker Inventory and PO Integration

Tags: filemaker, xero-api

The company I work for in the the process of converting to Xero from MYOB. I'm currently developing a Filemaker database that will handle Estimates, Jobs, Inventory, Purchase Orders, and several other entities. I'm trying to work out the best way to sync Inventory items. We will have multiple stock locations, and product categories, in the Filemaker database, so according to https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api-guides/inventory-integration-options we should only sync inventory transactions, not inventory items.

The issue with this is that for the foreseeable future we will still be using ServiceM8 for the service side of the business. Filemaker is only used for estimates and jobs for the install side of the business, as well as purchase orders and inventory. ServiceM8 will still need to push invoices to Xero and adjust stock quantities accordingly. Is it a viable option to sync inventory items but just have an QuantityOnHand field in the filemaker database that is a sum of all the stock location quantities, and sync that with the Xero QuantityOnHand field?

Likewise there will be category fields in the filemaker product table that will not be seen in the Xero product table, but all product record creation will be done in Filemaker. Worst case I can periodically find any product records that do not have categories and enter them.

One other thing, I hope it's OK to put it in the same topic as it's related.:
Filemaker will handle purchase orders including Receiving multiple shipments. Would best practice be to POST the purchase order record to Xero when it's created and update the Status as necessary, or should I not use purchase orders in Xero at all and just  do stock transactions?

Thanks,
Stew.

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking. SO is designed to deal with a specific programming problem and not a general discussion. One of the FileMaker forums will be better suited for this.